# Combine array columns to create an array of struct

Tags: arrays, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, struct

How can I combine two array columns 'languages' and 'languages2' to come up with an array 'lang' which is array of struct:

`languages1 = ["Java1","Scala1","C++1"]`
`languages2 = ["Java2","Scala2","C++2"]`

I need to create a new column 'lang' with below data for the above row:

```
lang:
[ data:{
   language:Java1,
   languages2: Java2
   },
  data:{
   language:scala1,
   languages2: scala2
   },
  data:{
   language:c++1,
   languages2: c++2
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`arrays_zip`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_zip.html#pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_zip) seems could help.

> Collection function: Returns a merged array of structs in which the N-th struct contains all N-th values of input arrays.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(["Java1", "Scala1","C++1"], ["Java2", "Scala2","C++2"])],
    ['languages1', 'languages2'])


df = df.select(F.arrays_zip('languages1', 'languages2').alias('lang'))

df.show(truncate=0)
# +------------------------------------------------+
# |lang                                            |
# +------------------------------------------------+
# |[{Java1, Java2}, {Scala1, Scala2}, {C++1, C++2}]|
# +------------------------------------------------+

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- lang: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
#  |    |    |-- languages1: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- languages2: string (nullable = true)
```